# camera not taking pictures on button press

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am using the following code to use the camera to take a picture when a button is pressed.

However when I run the code it only starts the camera app after **the button is pressed but does not take a picture.  Why is this not working?**

***I wanted to take a picture when the button is pressed and store that on the SD card that can be viewed in the gallery app.***

```
public class demo extends Activity 
{
Button ButtonClick;
int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ButtonClick =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Camera);
ButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ()
   {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // request code

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

    }
  });

 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
   if( requestCode == 1337)
   {
   //  data.getExtras()
      Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");          
   }
   else 
   {
    Toast.makeText(demo.this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
}
```

Comment: **R u capturing pic once the camera is opened ??**

Comment: no, how do i do that?,   i thought that it would get the pic/bitmap when the button is pressed.  but if i have to explicitly capture the picture than it is one step that i have not done.

Comment: You need to go one more step dude by clicking pic, For capturing pic once the camera app is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this the default behavior. there are two ways.

1) Start camera app intent(you are doing so), then click picture via camera app(like default camera does, by clicking on camera take picture button or hard key.)

2) Create your custom camera view by using Camera class and Surfaceview. It will give you full control to do whatever u want with camera(limited though)

Comment: I wanted to be able for the camera to take a pic without needing to click anything.  like set a timer to take a pic every 5 minutes or have it take a pic when a motion detector tells it to.  so I will have to set up surfaceview then.

Comment: So in this case, your own camera app will be in front all the time??. or do you think u need to do it from Service or something. and one more question by clicking pic you mean pic from camera or Screenshot?

Comment: yes, i was going to make the app on the front all the time.  i wanted to attach a motion sensor to the camera to detect motion and take a picture when there is motion, but that is the final step. the first step is to get it to take a picture with an on click listener.  after i get that to work then i will do the more advanced part of getting the motion sensor to make the camera take a picture.  but it works the same way.  if i can make a button onclick listener click to make it take a picture, then i can do the same with a motion sensor.

Comment: i am making a security camera out of an old android phone, and it will sit there all the time running only this one app.  one idea is to have it connected to a motion sensor with an arduino board, or the other idea is to have it detect motion by taking pictures every second and determine if there is change in the latest picture and that will make it save that picture because there was motion in the area.  either way can work.  the first job is to be able to make the andorid phone camera take a picture without needing someone to press the take picture button.

Comment: Yeah then SurfaceView with Camera class is a best choice. All the best for your app. If u need any help Please ping me on "ankit.awasthi1@gmail.com"